# How to test the Facebook Marketing API if my ad account doesn't have any ads or campaigns?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-insights

I'm working on extracting ads insights data from Facebook using the marketing API in Python and add these data to MySQL database, Now I'm trying to test the codes and get myself familiar with the API but my ad account doesn't have any ads or campaigns yet so I got an empty response when I try something like this:

`AdAccount('act_********').get_insights()`

So is there a way to get a dummy response from the API just to make myself familiar with the actual response that will be shown if there are ads in the account?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use sandbox mode to create campaigns (or ad sets/ads). See [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/best-practices/):

> You can use sandbox mode to demonstrate your app for app review. However in sandbox mode you cannot create ads or ad creative.

Facebook's Marketing API is quite limited when it comes to testing, especially compared to Google Ads API, unfortunately.